# Error trying to use a pdf file located in my project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am making an application which inserts text into a pdf template, but I am encountering a problem and it is that when I want to use the template it is as if I could not find it, so I did a validation with File.Exists, and it effectively returns me false, but when I look for the same path in the file explorer it finds me the pdf without problems.
This is my code:

```
protected void btn_Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string newName = $"numdoc_{ddl_TipoCapacitacion.SelectedValue}-{lastId.Rows[0]["ID"]}-{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("/", String.Empty)}.pdf";
        file = Path.Combine(location, newName);
        string oldFile = string.Concat(Server.MapPath($@"~/plantillasPdf/capacitaciones/plantillaDiploma.pdf"));
        string newFile = string.Concat(Server.MapPath($@"~/plantillasPdf/capacitaciones/{newName}"));
        if (!File.Exists(oldFile))
        {
        }
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
        ...
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ControlarExcepcion(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to Concat here?

Comment: Use a debugger or otherwise print out what the value of `oldFile` & `newFile` are.

Comment: Your if block is empty, so the effect of executing it is the same whether File.Exists(...) is true or false.

Comment: @Neil If I have already done that, and that value is what I look for in the window explorer and it finds the file for me, while in .net it appears that it does not exist and generates the following error, not found as file or resource.

Comment: @jwdonahue I only use the if block to know if the file exists, where I use it is after the if block, which is where it generates the error

Comment: What are the folder separators?  forward slash / or backward slash \ ?  Maybe you need to use Path.Combine to get the right separator for your OS ?

Comment: Does the pdf open or download when you put the url in the browser directly? `http://yoursitename/plantillasPdf/capacitaciones/plantillaDiploma.pdf`

Comment: @Neil it does it with '\', and the same path works for me elsewhere, it just fails for me in this code snippet.

Comment: It's possible that 'elsewhere' do further conversions to make it work.  If you are running on Windows, then backslash should be OK.  How about opening a command line window and trying "dir <path>" to see if it the file is right.

Comment: Don't waste your time troubleshooting the slash direction. The virtual path passed to MapPath uses `/`. The return value will be a physical path appropriate for your OS.

Comment: If you are run your project in debug or release from Visual Studio the working directiry will be the .exe output directory not the projects one... please check your paths keeping in mind this

Comment: @MarcoBeninca its not that kind of application. It is webforms - there is no .exe

Comment: @Crowcoder it's the same... the working directory is the binaries output directory

Comment: @MarcoBeninca no,  a webforms app runs out of the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder for the given .NET framework version.